# Disable Bootstrap carousel on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got a multi-item carousel just the way I want it. However, I don't want to have carousel in my mobile view. Instead I'm using this code below so users can scroll horizontally in mobile:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .scroller {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .scroller .col-sm-4 {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 70%;
    }
}
```

But it's not working because Bootstrap carousel is called in all screen sizes. Could you help so that carousel works only in non-mobile device and then gets replace with the `scroller` class in mobile?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Use Bootstrap's carousel to show multiple items per slide.</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="scroller carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/f44336/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/e91e63/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/9c27b0/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/673ab7/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/4caf50/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.multi-item-carousel{
  .carousel-inner{
    > .item{
      transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
    }
    .active{
      &.left{
        left:-33%;
      }
      &.right{
        left:33%;
      }
    }
    .next{
      left: 33%;
    }
    .prev{
      left: -33%;
    }
    @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
      > .item{
        // use your favourite prefixer here
        transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
        transition: 500ms ease-in-out all;
        backface-visibility: visible;
        transform: none!important;
      }
    }
  }
  .carouse-control{
    &.left, &.right{
      background-image: none;
    }
  }
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.multi-item-carousel').carousel({
  interval: false
});

// for every slide in carousel, copy the next slide's item in the slide.
// Do the same for the next, next item.
$('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  } else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

**[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxZQPr)**